# Importing data to Mysql Table on Contao 3.2.x

Tags: import-from-csv, contao

Is there any extension that can I use to import hundreds data data from CSV/Excel to a mysql table in Contao? 
 
I tried to use the only CSV Import extension from extension catalog. 
But, unfortunately too many restrictions to allow an import. 

 
I knew we can manipulate anything from phpmyadmin, but I want to make module/feature for non-coder.

I just want to know if there are some alternatives for that, before I decided to develop one..

P.S 
This is the  [link](https://github.com/markocupic/import_from_csv)  to the extension I used previously

 so if anyone have any reccomendation, please do comment  :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem a while ago and what I found to be the best way was to develop my own extension. 
Mostly because you can do all kind of data handling before writing into your DB.

My case was importing members and assigning a password per member. Worked like a charm.

Hope that helps.